# Vue3 + Typescript, unable to add v-model on textarea

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to add v-model to a  element in my Vue component, but i get the following error, and I don't understand why:

`Property 'textInput' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{}>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>;`

Component:

```
<template>
  <h1>Check how often a word is repeated in your text:</h1>
  <textarea
    name="userInput"
    id="userInput"
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    v-model="textInput"
  ></textarea>

  <CheckButton />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import CheckButton from "./CheckButton.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "FrequencyBox",
  components: {
    CheckButton,
  },
});
</script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `textInput` reactive with the `ref` and return it:

Please check snippet below:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: "#demo",
  setup() {
    const textInput = ref(null)
    return { textInput }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h3>Check how often a word is repeated in your text:</h3>
  <textarea
    name="userInput"
    id="userInput"
    cols="30"
    rows="5"
    v-model="textInput"
  ></textarea>
  {{ textInput }}
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case this doesn't fix the error

Comment: But it should. You should add `data` option to your script and your `textInput` field into it (if you use options API) or use `ref` as suggested above (if you use composition API). Your error says that you're trying to bind a value to a field that doesn't exist.